# 3par OS location

Tags: hp, storage-area-network, fibre-channel

As a complete 3par Newbie I have a simple question about the OS of the Storage-System. Is the OS on a 3par stored on it's controllers or on Disks like in some EMC-Models. When I have an empty 3par-Controller-Node - Can I just add disks when the Controller-Node is licensed or do I need the preconfigured disks from HP because there is the OS installed?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

InFormOS is stored on the controllers.  If you are starting an array from scratch, you will need to do an Out of the Box procedure.  If the array is already configured, you will need to run an add command to bring the new disks into the storage pool.

With older 3PAR F-class, T-class, some 7000 series, if the disk was the matching model it would work and flash with new firmware.

Currently, it's similar, but HP has made a whole new list of acceptable drives, and the older ones are no longer in the firmware database.  Also, on newer 3par arrays, they need to have 520-byte format, not 512-byte format.

Answer (score -4):

If we compare EMC and HPe3par.

We have architecture difference.

1. In old EMC model disk arrays we had a (I mean EMC Clarrion) Windows OS/later Linux in coffer/vault disk (4 disk), (Right now I dont know).
   HpE 3par don't have coffer/vault disk. OS installed on storage controller. I don't remember but i think maybe in flash card.  Os it is a Linux - RHEL/OEL/Centos.
2. About empty controller mode I don't understand question.
   a. Basicly you can use your massive and work with your disks. But you need understand about cpg and chunklets. 
   b. I don't remember but if you mean license for disk capacity. And if you going  to increase a disk capacty and you don't have a license. You will be have a problem.

Comment: Minus did not put only lazy.                                                                                                       Why don't like HUawei OceanStore ? OceanStore have a 4 coffer disks, and operation system installed in storage controller. (It is Huawei depvelopment). I think for Huawei need to give a chance.